# Error with unix time generation

Tags: c#, .net, unix, time

I am trying to generate a unix time stamp and have to send a webrequest that has initial time and response time

I tried this code

```
long ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00").Ticks;
ticks /= 10000;
string timestamp = ticks.ToString() + "000000";
label1.Text = timestamp;
int k=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   k = k + i;
}
long ticks2 = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970 00:00:00").Ticks;
ticks2 /= 10000;
string timestamp2 = ticks.ToString() + "000000";
label2.Text = timestamp2;
```

I have to send request like this

```
{
    "options": {
        "events": [
            {
                "event_type": 13,
                "view_type": 1,
                "view_parameter": 92,
                "request_identifier": %2",
                "time": 1382060060538000000,
                "event_data": {}
            }
        ],
        "report_time": 1382060072238000000
    },
    "context": {
        "app_version":"6590b21"
    }
}
```

Error is, output on both the label box are same http://prntscr.com/1y0v7p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `string timestamp2 = ticks.ToString() + "000000";` to `string timestamp2 = ticks2.ToString() + "000000";`

Answer (score 1):

That's way too complex! Just do this:

```
var unixTime = (dateTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds + "000000";
```